# C#: Class with a variable whose data type varies

Tags: c#

I'm trying to define a class with a variable named `x`, whose type matches some generic `T`. This is easy to achieve:

```
public class Test<T>{
    public T x{get; set;}
}
```

The problem is that I would like to be able to talk about `Test` instances with different `T`s simultaneously, such as in declaring a `List<Test>` having elements of types `Test<T>`, `Test<S>`, etc. Here's what I tried:

```
public interface ITest{
    object x {get; set;}
}

public interface ITest<T> : ITest{
    T x {get; set;}
}

public class Test<T> : ITest<T>{
    public T x {get; set;}
}
```

This has the effect of hiding `x`, but what I'm really trying to do is "be more specific" about the type that `x` has. The error from the above is:

`'Test<T>' does not implement interface member 'ITest.x'. 'Test<T>.x' cannot implement 'ITest.x' because it does not have the matching return type of 'object'`

Is there some way to downcast the type that `x` has in `ITest<T>`?

Comment: `T` can already be `object`, so I don't know why you need two interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track. Your only problem is that `ITest.x` has the same name as `Test.x`. If you make the properties have different names then `Test` can implement `ITest`:

```
    public interface ITest
    {
        object untypedX { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ITest<T> : ITest
    {
        T x { get; set; }
    }

    public class Test<T> : ITest<T>
    {
        public T x { get; set; }
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public object untypedX { get=>x; set=>x=(T)value; }
    }
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I wanted. I was fixated on giving the variables the same name and didn't think about using the setter implementation to cast. Thank you.